# Designing the programming list block in LyX

Tags: lyx, programming

I'm new to `LyX`. I'm trying to create a programming block of some `PL` which looks like in the picture bellow:

[image]

Tried to look for some similar threads, bud didn't find any.

How can I make make the programming list to look as in the picture?

Comment: mind showing your effort?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For typesetting source code have a look at the [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package

Answer (score 1):

In LyX, do Insert > Program Listing. For more information, see Help > Embedded Objects, Section 8 "Program Code Listings".